# Node.js: how to load modules without executing them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a simple file `model.js` like follows:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/mydb';

exports.connect = mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db) {
    console.log("Connect to the database successfully")
});
```

and in my `web.js` I load the model using `model = require('./model.js')`. One werid thing is that although I did not call `model.connect()`, the message "Connect to the database successfully" still got logged to my console. Why is this happening and is there a way to avoid it?

*EDIT*:Never mind I have found a workaround:

```
exports.connect = function(){
     mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db) {
        console.log("Connect to the database successfully")
     });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exports.connect = mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db) {
    console.log("Connect to the database successfully")
});
```

You just called `mongo.Db.connect()` and assigned its *result* to `exports.connect`.
That code runs as soon as you `require()` the module.

Instead, you need to create a function:

```
exports.connect = function() { ... };
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I just discovered the error myself too :)